# How to get all items from IMongoCollection in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
var users = database.GetCollection<ApplicationUser>("users");
```

There is no `FindAll` function in Mongodb.driver 2.0.

Answer (score 15):

Ugly straightforward approach:

```
await (await users.FindAsync(_ => true)).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: the question is because of mongo new driver has changed syntacsis but existing exmaples are obsolete

Answer (score 14):

You should find with empty filter like `users.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ

```
var collection = _db.GetCollection("users");
return (from x in collection.AsQueryable()
         select x["something"]).toList();
```

Or maybe if you are in somewhere near Mongo Driver 2.7 version the below query would compile. (note also that generic parameter of Users is redundant here)

```
List<string> q2=(from x in collection.AsQueryable<users>() select x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: in mongodb driver 2.0 , GetCollection will return IMongoCollection<T> , there is no AsQueryable() method in  IMongoCollection<T>

Comment: @iwaitu They seem to have severly crippled `IMongoCollection` -- it's not even `IEnumerable`! What the heck?!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this way, because have Cleaner code (maybe this code doesn't work in older versions of mongoDb Driver).

`_db.GetCollection("users").Aggregate().ToList();`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.